# How to get the cookies in webservice using silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller, web-services

I have  an ASP.Net MVC Application ,from this I pass the  .ASPXAUTH cookie to silverlight application .

I am able to get this cookie using HtmlPage.Document.Cookies.Split(';');. Now I want to   pass this cookie to my webservice through headers ,so that based on this I can authenticate the user .How can I set in silverlight apllication and then get cookies in webservice .

Thanks in Advance

DNM